# C++ catch(std::exception & e ) vs. catch(...)

Tags: c++, exception

I know the difference in handling of both of these catches, but what does it take for the ellipse to catch something the std::exception catch wouldn't catch?

For example:

```
try
{
    throw std::runtime("runtime error!");
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception: " << e;
}
catch(...)
{
    std::cout << "How did I get here?";
    throw;
}
```

I've seen examples of code that use both of these in conjunction, but I've not seen a reason you would do both.

Comment: What if the code inside the `try` doesn't throw an exception based on `std::exception`?

Comment: If you come from Java or C#, then note that in C++ you can throw basically any type or object. You don't have to use class inheriting from `std::exception`

Comment: `throw 42;` for example...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
catch(const std::exception& e)
```

Will catch std exceptions only.

```
catch(...)
```

Will catch everything there after.

You can handle integers and other types (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)

For example:

```
catch(int e)
```

Comment: I had this question, found the answer and couldn't find a question like this on SO.

Comment: [Self answers are indeed encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). If it was your intention all along, it'd be best in the future to write the Q&A together. There's a checkbox at the bottom of the "ask a question" page that opens up an answer panel.

Comment: Snap, I knew there was a way to make it a self answer, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

While it's definitely a good idea to do so, you don't *have* to derive your custom exceptions from `std::exception`. C++ allows you to throw practically any object type.

So `throw 1;` will not be handled by your first handler, for example. And neither will...

```
class MyCustomException { // Doesn't derive
 ///
};
```

... if it was thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant:

```
throw std::runtime_error("runtime error!"); // not std::runtime
```

The [std::runtime_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) is derived from the [std::exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) so your first catch block is fired up as it catches exceptions of type `std::exception`. And there you probably meant:

```
std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what(); // not e
```

If you threw anything else other than the `std::run_time` or `std::exception` and its derivatives, the second `catch` block would be triggered. Useful reading from the C++ FAQ: 
[What should I throw?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#what-to-throw)

Answer (score 0):

As written, the `throw` statement throws an object whose type is derived from `std::exception`, so it's caught by the first `catch` clause. If you change the throw to `throw 3;` the exception will be caught by the second `catch` clause, not the first.