# Should I write catch (...) after catch (exception& e)?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, try-catch

If I know that in the code there is no programmer-defined exception and want to catch only the one thrown by standard libs, is it enough just to write `catch (std::exception& e)`, or I still need to write after it `catch (...)` ?

```
int main()
{
try 
{//something
}
catch (std::exception& e) { /*something*/}
catch (...) {/*something*/} //unnecessary? 
}
```

So basically it's a question about can I be sure that all `throw` from `std` methods and functions are exception derived from `std::exception`?

Comment: Pretty sure all C++ library exceptions are derived from `std::exception` but, who knows. One thing that Java does better than C++ is strong type checking and enforcement. Wouldn't be nice if a failure to catch an exception resulted in ill-formed code and compiler diagnostic?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ catch(std::exception & e ) vs. catch(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49877965/c-catchstdexception-e-vs-catch)

Comment: @scohe001 no, as I know the difference, and a question is basically can I be sure that all throw from std are exception delivered from std::exception

Answer (score 2):

My answer: It depends.

What's your purpose in catching the exception? Can you do anything about it? Are you simply logging its existence, or making a friendly report to the user rather than a crash? How big is the codebase? How certain are you there are no exceptions thrown that are not in the standard exception hierarchy?

I've done this sometimes, usually when I hit an uncaught exception and was trying to debug it. I'll include the `catch (...)` in there just in case somebody stuck a `throw 42;` or something equally brilliant in there. But generally, I don't really use them in real code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) says:

> All exceptions generated by the standard library inherit from
> std::exception.